# Bash history between two points in time

Tags: bash, shell, history, built-in

I would like to do something like

```
history 2960-2966
```

with the expectation of this kind of output:

```
2960  2013-12-09 20:59:35 bundle update
2961  2013-12-09 21:00:08 git st
2962  2013-12-09 21:00:12 git add .
2963  2013-12-09 21:01:19 git st
2964  2013-12-09 21:01:43 git log
2965  2013-12-09 21:02:45 git st
2966  2013-12-09 21:02:57 git reset HEAD Gemfile.lock
```

Is this possible in the bash shell?

UPDATE:  My question is about seeing those seven history rows, not the dates, per se; it just happens that I have a `HISTTIMEFORMAT` directive in my .bash_profile to give the date and time stamp.  If I were to remove it then I would wish `history 2960-2966`, or *something*, to generate this output:

```
2960  bundle update
2961  git st
2962  git add .
2963  git st
2964  git log
2965  git st
2966  git reset HEAD Gemfile.lock
```

I want the desired history rows to be displayed, preferably with any customization I've specified in .bash_profile.

Why would I want this?  A very simple use case is: I do something like `history | grep 'bundle update'` get a decent result, then want to see some history from that point plus a few lines farther along, or maybe the history bracketing that point.

Comment: You should be able to do this using [Git Tags](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag).  See the bottom of the page.

Comment: As @Tharanga Abeyseela notices in his answer, I have a date display in my history due to a `HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '` directive in my .bash_profile.

Comment: Hey @Brian, this question isn't about git at all, those just happened to be the lines at that point in my history.

Comment: There is a [way for storing history sessions in mysql](http://superuser.com/a/520638/178656) (as *one DB entry by shell seession*) and there is a [way for storing whole shell sessions](http://superuser.com/a/579244/178656) (able to *replay*) in separated files.

Comment: I guess you firstly have to set history to store the timestamp, http://larsmichelsen.com/open-source/bash-timestamp-in-bash-history/ Do you have that?

Comment: I hope people don't get distracted by the YYYY-MM-DD strings in my output.  That's just there because of the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` I have in my .bash_profile.  I would like that a solution to my question work no matter how my history command is guided by formatting options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sed`.  Say:

```
history | sed -n '2960,2966p'
```

to print line numbers 2960 to 2966 from the output of `history` command.

Quoting `help history`:

```
If the $HISTTIMEFORMAT variable is set and not null, its value is used
as a format string for strftime(3) to print the time stamp associated
with each displayed history entry.  No time stamps are printed otherwise.
```

You could set the format to get the timestamp in the desired format by saying:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
```

Since the `history` file is written by default only upon session close, you'd need to say:

```
history -w
```

in order to update the history file in the current session.

Comment: This `sed` expression doesn't work for me.  There is no output displayed at all, whereas the histrange function I defined in my answer does work (on Ubuntu 12.04) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554927/bash-history-between-two-points-in-time/20604325#20604325.  Can you explain how this `sed` expression is supposed to work?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma this solution worked for me on OSX 10.9.1 (Mavericks).  Do you know why it doesn't work on Ubuntu?  I like devnull's solution because I could probably even just remember it, but is it not universal?

Comment: @Purplejacket - `history` presents a circular buffer - once the buffer is full, old entries will get overwritten by newer ones.  This means the `history` output might for example list entries 834-1833 of the history buffer if the buffer has already wrapped (as it apparently does at 1000 on Ubuntu).  So the line number of the `history` output doesn't necessarily correspond to the history entry number.  devnull's `sed` solution is keyed off the line number (by counting lines of output).  My solutions are keyed off the actual `history` entry numbers.

Comment: @Purplejacket You can try saying: `history | sed -n '/^\s*2960 /,/^\s*2966 /p'`

Answer (score 3):

fc -l 2960 2966

This works on OS 10.6.X. It gives exactly what you need. Hope this helps!

Comment: That is stunningly simple and good.  I can confirm that works in Linux Mint (Ubuntu derivative).  Do you know if it works in other unixes?

Comment: As near as I can tell, `fc` is widely available: http://alasir.com/books/bsd/211-214.html

Comment: @Purplejacket Thanks, Yes, you are right, as long as fc is available.

Comment: Does *anyone* else care about *why* it works, or *what* it does? Pragmatism is one thing, but even an excellent solution is building cargo cult behaviour without some explicit reasoning.

Comment: `fc` is a bash command utility (also available for other shells). You can use it to edit and re-run commands, if you use the `-l` flag, it will print to `stdout` (instead of opening your default editor). You can use numbers as indices to specify start and end points. A negative number is interpreted as an offset `fc -l -5` the 5 most recently ran commands.

Answer (score 1):

We want to display entries from `start` to `end` inclusive.

The `$HISTCMD` variable built into [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) gives [the number of the latest entry to the history buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-HISTCMD).
The `history` command takes an `n` parameter, which tells it to display the last `n` entries.  So the start number when displaying entries with the `n` parameter would be:

```
start = $HISTCMD - n
```

Rearranging in terms of `n` we get this expression which can be passed to `history`:

```
n = $HISTCMD - start
```

Now we want to display only the entries from `start` to `end` inclusive, i.e. `end - start + 1` entries.  We can use `head` to give just those enties.

Wrapping this up into an easy-to-use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function we have:

```
$ function histrange {
>     history $(($HISTCMD - $1)) | head -n$(($2 - $1 + 1))
> }
$ histrange 2097 2100
 2097  2013-12-15 21:54:02 man ls
 2098  2013-12-15 21:54:06 ls
 2099  2013-12-15 21:54:10 man df
 2100  2013-12-15 21:54:15 df -k .
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
$ function histrange {
> history | grep -E -A $(($2 - $1)) "^[[:space:]]*$1[[:space:]]"
> }
$ histrange 2100 2105
 2100  2013-12-15 21:54:15 df -k .
 2101  2013-12-15 21:54:18 history
 2102  2013-12-15 21:54:40 histrange 2097 2100
 2103  2013-12-15 21:55:30 man grep
 2104  2013-12-15 22:35:33 man history
 2105  2013-12-15 22:38:35 export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
$
```

We make sure the regular expression is anchored to the start of the line, has zero or more whitespace before the start number and one whitespace after the start number, so we only exactly match the start number to the history entry number and nothing else.  We use the `-A` option to `grep` to display the `$end - $start` lines following the match.

Answer (score 1):

Given what you say under why you want this,

```
history | grep -A 4 -B 3 whatyousearchfor
```

should give you just what you want.

The `whatyousearchfor` can either be your original serch term or you first do  grep without context lines and then use the history line number as `whatyousearchfor`.

Answer (score 0):

try the following command . this will display the range from 2960 to 2966

```
fc -ln 2960-2966
```

to execute them you can try this

```
eval "$(fc -ln 2960 2966)"
```

Hope this helps.

Tharanga Abeyseela

Comment: I tried that `fc` command and it displayed history lines from 2960 but didn't stop at 2966.

Comment: I don't need to re-run those history lines, just display them in a nice format.

Comment: how about history | grep -B6 2966

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but it will find other occurrences of the number 2966.

Comment: I frequently do `history | tail -n 50` but I can't think of a way to adapt that to two specific points in history.

Comment: other option is use regex pattern with grep.

Comment: try this  history | awk {'print $1 " "  $2'}| grep -B6  ^2966 | head -n 6

Comment: Looks better, but it doesn't print out the whole history line.  E.g., for line 2960 it just shows `2960 2013-12-09` rather than what you see in my question.

Comment: sorry, that make sense. i was using history command without the timestamp.($1,$2) do you care about the timestamp or just command and the line no  ?

Comment: In my .bash_profile I have `HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '` which is why I get that time format; so yes, it's a nice-to-have, but not a requirement.  Mostly I care about command and line number.

Comment: then remove the timestamp , and use  history | awk {'print $1 " " $2'}| grep -B6 ^2966 | head -n 6 . that should work.

Comment: Ah, you're suggesting to remove the HISTTIMEFORMAT.  I don't want to have to do that in order to get this feature.

Comment: try this  history | awk {'print $1,$4,$10'}| grep -B6 ^2966 | head -n 7

Answer (score 0):

```
$> export HISTTIMEFORMAT="    %F    %T     "
```

then:

```
$> history | awk '{if (1070<=$1 && $1<=1075) {print}}'
```

This is almost the response of devnull.
Never though to things like that before, but I liked the idea and think it will be usefull for me too. I get an approximative answer searching from the built-in bash help.

```
$> help history
```

> ...
>
> If the $HISTTIMEFORMAT variable is set and not null, its value is used
>     as a format string for strftime(3) to print the time stamp associated
>     with each displayed history entry.  No time stamps are printed otherwise.

then

```
$> man 3 srtftime
```